# Adding constraints with Google OR Tools on Class Variables

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a set of `Employees`, and each employee has an associated start time and end time. Each employee is a namedtuple, in Python.

```
Employee = namedtuple("Employee", ["start_time", "end_time", "name"])
```

Start time and end time are datetime.time() objects.
For example, `veronica = Employee(datetime.time(9, 30, 0), datetime.time(14, 30, 0), "Veronica")`

I am using Google OR Tools for Scheduling Optimization, and I want to add a constraint that only allows people who are available during that time frame to be placed in a specified shift.

How would I go about doing that? Thanks. Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you precompute each employee and each shift to filter which employee can work on which shift. Then add 1 boolean variables only for the compatible shifts ?

More generally for shift scheduling, you can have a look at:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py